# How can i run two manifests a single pipeline YAML?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, pipeline, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

i have a pipeline close with this one:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  imageName: 'gosample'
  registry: 'kubreg.azurecr.io'

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: 'BuildAndPush'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'ACR'
        repository: '$(imageName)'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'manifests'
        targetPath: 'manifests'

- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'DeployToK8S'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: dev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'current'
                artifactName: 'manifests'
                targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests'
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              inputs:
                action: 'deploy'
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'dev-kub-gosample-1558821689026'
                namespace: 'gosample'
                manifests: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deploy.yaml'
                containers: '$(registry)/$(imageName):$(Build.BuildId)'
```

And i want pass two manifests inside the deploy stage, how i can do?

I tried to pass something like:

```
manifests: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deploy.yaml','$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifest/ingress-nginx.yaml'
```

But Don't work and i really dont have idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can list multiple files by using a multiline string, [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v0?view=azure-pipelines#deploy-action).

```yaml
task: KubernetesManifest@0
inputs:
  manifests: |
    manifests/deployment.yml
    manifests/service.yml
```